How to make a bar chart for sales data in csv file
I'm trying to make a bar chart of customer sales value by date.
I have imported the CSV but I'm stuck on formatting the date.
In the file, each date reads like this: 01.08.2023 00:37.
Each date has multiple sales
I want to pull and display the date in a bar chart that only gives the date on the x-axis and the sales amount on the y-axis and at the top of the bars.
Link to the desired bar chart
Thanks

it looks like you are asking for help in CSV , not in python.

Here's an example that uses Pandas to group and sum randomly generated sales data.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, HourLocator


# create a date range
dt_range = pd.date_range(start='2024-08-01', end='2024-08-07', freq="4h")
# create some random sales
sales = np.random.randint(100, 600, len(dt_range))
# create a DataFrame with our data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":dt_range, "Sales":sales})

days = df["Date"].dt.floor("D")  # truncate days

# Group the summed Sales by days and plot 
ax = df.groupby(days)["Sales"].sum().plot.bar(title="Daily Sales")
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%m-%d'))

plt.show()

This produces something like this:

You might want to play around with the date formats on the x axis, check this example.
If you are struggling to convert your csv dates into datetime objects, check pandas.to_datetime. Pandas can also help you read your CSV file.
